# How to set different digit rounding specifications for labels with geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am attempting to label my bar graph with data rounded to one decimal point. However, I have values that are 0. I'd like to find someway to make sure that the zero values are not being displayed as `0.0`. I would like them to be displayed as `0`.

Here is what my plot looks like currently:
[image]

Code: `p2+geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%0.1f", pct)), position=position_dodge(width=0.7), vjust=-0.25, size=3)`

I approached this by attempting to not label the `0` values at all. However, this created a problem where my labels were not aligned properly. (note the label offset for `0.` for Native American in the furthest left panel).

[image]

Code: `p2+geom_text(data=subset(demo_long_pct,pct != 0),aes(label=sprintf("%0.1f", pct)), position=position_dodge(width=0.7), vjust=-0.25, size=3)`

Comment: maybe use `label= ifelse(pct==0, "0", sprintf("%0.1f", pct))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an ifelse statement in there. Something like this..

```
p2 + geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(test = pct == 0, yes = pct, no = sprintf("%0.1f", pct)), position=position_dodge(width=0.7), vjust=-0.25, size=3)
```

You could also replace the yes conditional argument with 0 if it still labelled with decimal points.

Comment: Excellent that did the trick! I think there may need to be a third parenthesis to end the aes, such that ```no = sprintf("%0.1f", pct)))```